# how to check database table permissions in java? (DataBase independently)

Tags: java, database, permissions

Does anyone know a way (in java) to check permissions to a specific table for a user? It has to work on the most Databases. SELECT right is simple to check (just trying to execute a simple SELECT statement), but how to check INSERT permission?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DatabaseMetaData` to get this information. It should work in most cases. However, it might be inaccurate in special cases, if the privileges can not be represented in this abstract way:

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData connection.getMetaData();
metaData.getTablePrivileges();
metaData.getColumnPrivileges();
```

Answer (score 0):

though not a direct solution but the only option that comes to my mind is to use TRY CATCH blocks, issue an INSERT statement and then checking the error message in java.sql.SQLException  object returned in case of exception.

Comment: it is not a good idea for many reasons. For example, because there can be some triggers in database.